# r for loop with if else statement and reference to outcome of previous iteration

Tags: r, for-loop

I am having a dataframe with field x containing both group names (labeled as letters in the example below) and members of the group (listed *under* the group names, labeled as a number). I want to create a field that shows for each member the name of its group. In the dataframe below the desired output is shown in column "outcome".

```
df <- data.frame("x"=c("A","1","2","B","C","1","2","C","D","1"),
                 "outcome"=c("A","A","A","B","C","C","C","C","D","D")
) %>%
  mutate(
    Letter = ifelse(grepl("[A-Za-z]", x) == T,"Letter",
                      "No Letter")
  )
```

My idea is to do this via a forloop. If x is a letter it should return that letter, if not it should return the outcome of the previous loop (which is the previous found letter in x).
The forloop below doesn't give the right output:

```
df$outcome_calc[1] <- "A" 
for (i in 2:10) {  
  df$outcome_calc[i] <- ifelse(df$Letter[i] == "No Letter",df$outcome_calc[i-1],df$x[i])    

}
```

Any ideas how to get the right output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do this using `for` loop:

```
# keeps track of previous letter
prev = ''

# output
op = c()

for (i in df$x){

    # check the pattern
    check = grepl(pattern = '[a-zA-Z]', x = i, ignore.case = T)

    if(isTRUE(check)){
        op = c(op, i)
        prev = i
    } else {
        op = c(op, prev)
    }

}

print(op)
[1] "A" "A" "A" "B" "C" "C" "C" "C" "D" "D"
```

Comment: Thank you YOLO. Although maybe not the most efficient one in large datasets it is most readable to me.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two `tidyverse` ways, very similar, using the convenience function [`zoo::na.locf`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/zoo/versions/1.8-6/topics/na.locf).

**First:**

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(na = is.na(as.numeric(as.character(x))),
         outcome2 = ifelse(na, as.character(x), NA_character_),
         outcome2 = zoo::na.locf(outcome2)) %>%
  select(-na)
```

**Another one:**

```
df %>%
  mutate(chr = !grepl("[[:digit:]]", x),
         outcome2 = ifelse(chr, as.character(x), NA_character_),
         outcome2 = zoo::na.locf(outcome2)) %>%
  select(-chr)
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can avoid `for` loop by using `sapply` function.

You can define the position of your letters:

```r
pos_letter <- grep("[A-Za-z]", df$x)
```

Then, use `sapply` to 1) define for each row, the position of the letter right above and finally replaced each values by the corresponding letter:

```r
df$out <- sapply(1:nrow(df),function(x) max(pos_letter[pos_letter <= x]))
df$out2 <- sapply(df$out, function(x) x = as.character(df[x,"x"]))

   x outcome out out2
1  A       A   1    A
2  1       A   1    A
3  2       A   1    A
4  B       B   4    B
5  C       C   5    C
6  1       C   5    C
7  2       C   5    C
8  C       C   8    C
9  D       D   9    D
10 1       D   9    D
```

You can combine both `sapply` function in a single line by writing:

```r
sapply(1:nrow(df), function(n) as.character(df[max(pos_letter[pos_letter <= n]),"x"]))

[1] "A" "A" "A" "B" "C" "C" "C" "C" "D" "D"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `tidyr::fill` - requires NAs where your numbers were:

```
df = data.frame(x = c("A","1","2","B","C","1","2","C","D","1"),
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df$x[grepl("[0-9]+", df$x)] = NA

tidyr::fill(df, x)
   x
1  A
2  A
3  A
4  B
5  C
6  C
7  C
8  C
9  D
10 D
```

Answer (score 0):

#### `dplyr`

Here is a stream-lined version of [Rui's 2nd approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59517738/3817004) which doesn't require to create a temporary helper column. It uses `stringr::str_detect()`, `if_else()`, and `zoo::na.locf()`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(outcome2 = if_else(stringr::str_detect(x, "\\D"), x, factor(NA)) %>% zoo::na.locf())
```

> ```
>    x outcome    Letter outcome2
> 1  A       A    Letter        A
> 2  1       A No Letter        A
> 3  2       A No Letter        A
> 4  B       B    Letter        B
> 5  C       C    Letter        C
> 6  1       C No Letter        C
> 7  2       C No Letter        C
> 8  C       C    Letter        C
> 9  D       D    Letter        D
> 10 1       D No Letter        D
> ```

#### `data.table`

For the sake of completeness, here is also `data.table` approach which I have used frequently. It uses *assignment by reference* to update `df`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[x %like% "\\D", outcome2 := x][, outcome2 := zoo::na.locf(outcome2)][]
```

> ```
>     x outcome    Letter outcome2
>  1: A       A    Letter        A
>  2: 1       A No Letter        A
>  3: 2       A No Letter        A
>  4: B       B    Letter        B
>  5: C       C    Letter        C
>  6: 1       C No Letter        C
>  7: 2       C No Letter        C
>  8: C       C    Letter        C
>  9: D       D    Letter        D
> 10: 1       D No Letter        D
> ```